# Сохранение данных в БД (Update)

Tags: c#, ado.net

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла проблема при сохранение изменений в БД.
Не получается сохранить изменения в БД, с помощью CommandBulder-a, т.к в моей базе нет первичного ключа, хотелось бы узнать как вручную можно обновить базу?

```
     private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect.Open();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlSelect, connect);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommandBuilder build = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.UpdateCommand = build.GetUpdateCommand();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        adapter.Update(ds);
        ds.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        connect.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Update complete");
```

Поискал на форуме и вроде как нашел ответ, но не получается занести в DataSet текущее значение, а не просто выборкой Select.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
         SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Opr SET col1=@col1, col2=@col2, col3=@col3, col4=@col4, col5=@col5", connect);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.NChar).SourceColumn = "col1";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.NChar).SourceColumn = "col2";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SourceColumn = "col3";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@col4", SqlDbType.NChar).SourceColumn = "col4";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@col5", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SourceColumn = "col5";
        adapter.UpdateCommand = comm;
        adapter.Update(ds);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, всем спасибо!

```
        //Form1()
        ds = new DataSet();
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlSelect, connect);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        OperGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        /*Delete*/
        string query = "Delete From Opr" +
                " where col1 = @col1  and col2 = @col2 and col3 = @col3 and col4=@col4 and col5=@col5";
        adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
        SqlParameterCollection pc;
        SqlParameter p;
        pc = adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters;
        p = pc.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col1");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
        p = pc.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col2");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
        p = pc.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col3");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
        p = pc.Add("@col4", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col4");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
        p = pc.Add("@col5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col5");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;

        /*Insert*/
        query = "INSERT INTO Opr (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4, @col5)";
        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
        pc = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters;
        pc.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col1");
        pc.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col2");
        pc.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col3");
        pc.Add("@col4", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col4");
        pc.Add("@col5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col5");

        /*Update*/
        query = "UPDATE Opr SET col1 = @col1, col2 = @col2, col3 = @col3, col4 = @col4, col5 = @col5 WHERE col1 = @oldcol1, col2 = @oldcol2, col3 = @oldcol3, col4 = @oldcol4, col5 = @oldcol5";
        adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connect);
        pc = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters;
        pc.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col1");
        p = pc.Add("@oldcol1", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col1");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

        pc = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters;
        pc.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col2");
        p = pc.Add("@oldcol2", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col2");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

        pc = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters;
        pc.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col3");
        p = pc.Add("@oldcol3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col3");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

        pc = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters;
        pc.Add("@col4", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col4");
        p = pc.Add("@oldcol4", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "col4");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

        pc = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters;
        pc.Add("@col5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col5");
        p = pc.Add("@oldcol5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "col5");
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        MessageBox.Show("Update complete");
    }

private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        if (OperGridView.SelectedRows != null)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow i in OperGridView.SelectedRows)
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[i.Index].Delete();
        }
```